# SvelteKit: How to force a download from a form action

Tags: forms, download, svelte, sveltekit

I'm working on a small web app where you can upload a file using an html form. That file then gets processed which creates another file the user is supposed to download. How do I force the browser to download the file instead of displaying it?

Currently I have

```
throw redirect(303, "/files/" + nameOfResultFile)
```

as the last line of my form action inside the `+page.server.ts`. It works, but it makes the browser display the result file which the user then has to "save page as". I want the download to start automatically.